# Reading file, matching strings and formatting the output in Perl

Tags: excel, perl, csv

spent to long on this and it is now hurting my head.  I have simplified the data file but basically I have grep'd some values out of 5 different files and now want to graph them into excel.  So the format in excel for a line graph needs to correct.

Current file looks like

```
Report-20140521.csv: Sun, 20
Report-20140530.csv: Sun, 23
Report-20140606.csv: Sun, 24
Report-20140613.csv: Sun, 25
Report-20140621.csv: Sun, 21
Report-20140521.csv: Mon, 22
Report-20140530.csv: Mon, 23
Report-20140606.csv: Mon, 24
Report-20140613.csv: Mon, 24
Report-20140621.csv: Mon, 21
Report-20140521.csv: Tues, 22
Report-20140530.csv: Tues, 23
Report-20140606.csv: Tues, 20
Report-20140613.csv: Tues, 21
Report-20140621.csv: Tues, 21
```

I would like to flatten this all out and have five lines with the values in each like :-

```
                 Sun Mon Tue wed ..

Report-20140521.csv: 20  22  22
Report-20140530.csv: 23  23  23 
Report-20140606.csv: 24  24  20
Report-20140613.csv: 25  24  21
Report-20140621.csv: 21  21  21
```

Have looked at using arrays and arrays of arrays but either way the data seems to be rigged and can't get it to flatten out using the 5 different lines.  On top of this I need to keep the file name as this will be striped out into a date format later in excel.

Answer (score 0):

I think a hash of hashes would work well for this, since your Day of Week values are discrete and bounded.  Some variant of this might work:

```
use strict;

my %matrix;

open IN, 'yourfile.txt' or die $!;
while (<IN>) {
  chomp;
  my ($report, $val) = split /,/;
  my ($file, $dow) = split /: /, $report;

  $matrix{$file}{$dow} = $val;
}
close IN;

my @dow = qw(Sun Mon Tues Wed Thu Fri Sat);

foreach my $file (sort keys %matrix) {

  print $file, "\t";

  my $report_ref = $matrix{$file};

  foreach my $dow (@dow) {
    print $$report_ref{$dow}, "\t";
  }

  print "\n";
}
```

Sample output:

```
Report-20140521.csv      20      22      22
Report-20140530.csv      23      23      23
Report-20140606.csv      24      24      20
Report-20140613.csv      25      24      21
Report-20140621.csv      21      21      21
```

Comment: Side notes: it complains under `warnings`; `open my $IN, '<', 'yourfile.txt'` and `$report_ref->{$dow}` are recommended alternatives.

Comment: @mpapec -- I've been away from Perl for a couple of years but have noticed all recent snippets use "open my $IN" instead of "open IN," as you suggested.  Is this a recent change in methodology, or have I been doing it wrong all along?

Comment: It is not "wrong", but it brings some implications, ie. typeglob should be localized `local IN;` before `open` as it can clash due it's global nature.

Comment: Perl 5 version 6 introduced this in March 2000, together with the three-parameter form of `open`. It seems to have taken a long time to catch on, but it is now considered best practice to use both. Take a look at `perldelta` [File and directory handles can be autovivified](http://search.cpan.org/~gsar/perl-5.6.0/pod/perldelta.pod#File_and_directory_handles_can_be_autovivified) and 
[open() with more than two arguments](http://search.cpan.org/~gsar/perl-5.6.0/pod/perldelta.pod#open()_with_more_than_two_arguments)

Comment: Many thanks for this answer looks great, will have closer look tomorrow.  Appreciate your time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a hash of arrays to store your data in, and then print out values matching your column names (i.e. day):

```
use warnings;
use strict;

open my $in, '<', 'in.txt';

my (%data, @record, @day, @n);

while (<$in>){
    chomp;
    my @split = split(/\s/);
    push @record, $split[0];
    $split[1] =~ s/,//g;        
    push @day, $split[1];
    push @n, $split[2];
}

push @{$data{$record[$_]} }, [ $day[$_], $n[$_] ] for 0 .. $#record;

my @days = qw(Sun Mon Tues Wed Thu Fri Sat);

print "$_ " foreach (@days);
print "\n";

for my $report (sort keys %data){
    print "$report\t";
    for my $val (@{$data{$report}}){
        my ($day, $n) = @$val;
        foreach(@days){
            print "$n\t" if $day eq $_;
        }
    print "\n"; 
        }
}
```

Output:

```
Sun Mon Tues Wed Thu Fri Sat  
Report-20140521.csv:    20  22  22  
Report-20140530.csv:    23  23  23  
Report-20140606.csv:    24  24  20  
Report-20140613.csv:    25  24  21  
Report-20140621.csv:    21  21  21
```

Comment: What about *"wed .."*?

Comment: Many thanks for this answer looks great, will have closer look tomorrow.  Appreciate your time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

This solution does as you ask. It uses a hash `%headers` to convert the date names into column numbers as the data is read in, and produces a hash that is keyed by the CSV file name. The values of the hash are arrays of value pairs, each pair consisting of a column number and a value for that column

Once the data has been digested into the hash, it is scanned in sorted order of file name. An array `@info` is initialised to seven empty fields, and the column/value pairs in the hash are used to overwrite those columns that are provided

The maximum length of the file names is determined and used first in printing the `@headers` array of day names, and then the `@info` array for each hash entry

I hope this helps

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use List::Util 'max';
my $filename = 'current.txt';

open my $fh, '<', $filename or die qq{Unable to open "$filename" for input: $!};

my @headers = qw/ Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat /;
my %headers = map { $headers[$_] => $_ } 0 .. $#headers;

my %file_data;

while (<$fh>) {
  next unless my @fields = /(\S[^:]+:)\s+(\w{3})\w*, (\d+)/;
  my $file = shift @fields;
  $fields[0] = $headers{ucfirst lc $fields[0]};
  push @{ $file_data{$file} }, \@fields;
}

my $width = max map length, keys %file_data;
my $format = "%*s%3s %3s %3s %3s %3s %3s %3s\n";
printf $format, $width, '', @headers;

for my $file (sort keys %file_data) {
  my $days = $file_data{$file};
  my @info = ('') x 7;
  for my $day (@$days) {
    my ($index, $val) = @$day;
    $info[$index] = $val;
  }
  printf $format, $width, $file, @info;
}
```

**output**

```
                    Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat
Report-20140521.csv: 20  22  22                
Report-20140530.csv: 23  23  23                
Report-20140606.csv: 24  24  20                
Report-20140613.csv: 25  24  21                
Report-20140621.csv: 21  21  21
```

Comment: Many thanks for this answer looks great, will have closer look tomorrow.  Appreciate your time and effort.